# Setting a field constraint using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, valueerror

I am trying to set a field constraint for a specific field called 'node_id' for node layer.
Below is the code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("node_id")
constraint_expression = '"node_id"==0 or "node_id" == 1'
layer.setFieldConstraint(field_index, QgsFieldConstraints.Constraint(constraint_expression))
layer.updateFields()
```

I am facing this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"node_id" not NULL'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layer.setFieldConstraint(field_index, QgsFieldConstraints.ConstraintExpression)
layer.setConstraintExpression(field_index, '"node_id" in (0, 1)')
```

Comment: I want to set an expression like - 'node_id' ==1 or 0 no other value. So thats why I need expression @RainForest

Comment: I have edited the expression, need to set the expression for the specific field - Node id should have value 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you , this works

Comment: One small question: Is there any way to add a tooltip/placeholder for a field using pyqgis?

Comment: layer.setFieldAlias(field_index, 'This Field Alias')

Comment: This changes the field name. I want to change the placeholder text in the lineedit of a field as I am setting it to read-only, as it will be calculated from the backend in the plugin. Orelse, I want to add some information in the pop-up box (one which comes up after we add a feature) saying that the field is calculated from backend.